# Change bottom shape of map pins with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, google-maps

I am trying to achieve the below image with few divs, round background with similar to V-shape ( as shown in image below).
So Far I have tried this but could not achieve as in the image. I have added both before and after psuedo code for it. Any Help will be much Appreciated.

// Want to Achieve this:

[image]

[image]

//So far I have done this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="markar-container">
      <button>
        <h1>Pin 4</h1>
        <div class="outer-circle">
          <div class="inner-circle">
            <div class="text">AA</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
<style scoped>
.outer-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: #3ac371;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 21px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
}

.outer-circle::before {
  content: "";
  top: 75px;
  left: 24px;
  border-width: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  /* box-shadow: 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.dl-outer-circle::after {
  /* position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 73px;
  left: 30px;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #3ac371 transparent transparent;
  transform: rotate(-90deg); */
}
</style>
```

// and my pin looks like this:

[image]

Comment: you can create `svg` for the same and then use it as `pseudo` element on the div.

Comment: or ```clip-path``` and ```polygon```. have a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/).

Answer (score 0):

I created a `svg` for you took a lot of time. Hope it will help

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -24px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='72' height='48' viewBox='0 0 72 48' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0H72V16.7561C70.0823 16.2625 68.0718 16 66 16C52.7451 16 42 26.7452 42 40V48H30V40C30 26.7452 19.2549 16 6 16C3.92822 16 1.91772 16.2625 0 16.7561V0Z' fill='%23FF0000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pedam, Can we do this without any url ( content: url("data.... ) or without svg. I want to have the same example as my own and add bottom-border between the V-shape, will it work then. As because I want to have more control over my divs/element when I use psuedo element like hover and focus, and when using Hover and focus the background color and shape will change....

Comment: then you need to use `clip-path` which is quite complicated may [this](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) will help you.